i cloned an organization repository which was built on "vue": "2.6.14" after running "npm install" i got this error "could not resolve dependency"
i just cloned an organization repository and after that, i open vscode with same direcory and i ran this command "npm install" and i got this error  "npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve npm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving: frontend@0.1.0 npm ERR! Found: vue@2.6.14 npm ERR! node_modules/vue npm ERR! vue@"^2.6.14" from the root project npm ERR! peer vue@"^2.6.8" from @storybook/vue@6.5.16 npm ERR! node_modules/@storybook/vue npm ERR! dev @storybook/vue@"^6.5.16" from the root project npm ERR! 6 more (@tinymce/tinymce-vue, @vue/composition-api, ...) npm ERR! npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! dev vuetify-loader@"^1.7.0" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: vue@2.7.16 npm ERR! node_modules/vue npm ERR! peer vue@"^2.7.2" from vuetify-loader@1.9.2 npm ERR! node_modules/vuetify-loader npm ERR! dev vuetify-loader@"^1.7.0" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm ERR! See C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-12-13T10_46_42_905Z-debug-0.log" and here is the package.json file "{ "name": "frontend", "version": "0.1.0", "license": "MIT", "private": true, "scripts": { "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --skip-plugins @vue/cli-plugin-eslint", "build": "vue-cli-service build --skip-plugins @vue/cli-plugin-eslint", "lint": "vue-cli-service lint src", "test": "jest src", "test:watch": "jest --watch --no-cache", "test:coverage": "jest --collectCoverage", "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006", "build-storybook": "build-storybook" }, "dependencies": { "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue2": "^3.0.1", "@editorjs/editorjs": "^2.28.2", "@editorjs/header": "^2.7.0", "@editorjs/list": "^1.8.0", "@editorjs/paragraph": "^2.9.0", "@editorjs/table": "^2.2.1", "@editorjs/text-variant-tune": "^1.0.1", "@editorjs/underline": "^1.1.0", "@tinymce/tinymce-vue": "^3", "@vue/composition-api": "^1.7.2", "@wiris/mathtype-tinymce5": "^8.11.0", "axios": "^0.21.4", "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0", "chart.js": "^2.9.4", "ckeditor5": "^43.1.0", "ckeditor5-premium-features": "^43.1.0", "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0", "core-js": "^3.6.5", "editorjs-header-with-anchor": "^2.6.0", "editorjs-paragraph-with-alignment": "^3.0.0", "editorjs-text-alignment-blocktune": "^1.0.3", "sass-loader": "^10.0.0", "tinymce": "^7.3.0", "vue": "^2.6.14", "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1", "vue-loading-overlay": "3.0", "vue-router": "^3.5.2", "vue-toast-notification": "^0.6.2", "vuetify": "^2.4.0", "vuex": "^3.6.2" }, "devDependencies": { "@babel/core": "^7.20.12", "@editorjs/checklist": "^1.5.0", "@editorjs/delimiter": "^1.3.0", "@editorjs/inline-code": "^1.4.0", "@editorjs/link": "^2.5.0", "@editorjs/marker": "^1.3.0", "@editorjs/quote": "^2.5.0", "@editorjs/warning": "^1.3.0", "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.16", "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.16", "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.16", "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.16", "@storybook/builder-webpack4": "^6.5.16", "@storybook/manager-webpack4": "^6.5.16", "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13", "@storybook/vue": "^6.5.16", "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0", "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0", "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0", "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0", "babel-loader": "^8.3.0", "editorjs-change-case": "^0.0.3", "editorjs-hyperlink": "^1.0.6", "editorjs-text-color-plugin": "^2.0.2", "eslint": "^6.7.2", "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2", "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2", "jest": "^29.0.1", "sass": "~1.32.0", "scrollreveal": "^4.0.9", "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.2", "vue-cli-plugin-webpack-bundle-analyzer": "~4.0.0", "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11", "vue-toastification": "^1.7.14", "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0" }, "eslintConfig": { "root": true, "env": { "node": true }, "extends": [ "plugin:vue/essential", "eslint:recommended" ], "parserOptions": { "parser": "babel-eslint" }, "rules": {} }, "browserslist": [ ">0.2%", "not dead", "not op_mini all" ], "_id": "frontend@0.1.0", "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!", "engines": { "npm": ">=8.0.0 <9.0.0", "node": ">=16.0.0 <17.0.0" } } " and here is the webpack.base.config.js file "const path = require('path') module.exports = { resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue'], alias: { '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'), '@ui': path.resolve(__dirname, "src/ui"), } }, } "
and i tried running this command "npm install --legacy-peer-deps" the installion was completed  but with some warning and could not start the app

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
